# A prepaid sim card for vacations to use in France & UK? (2015)

Tags: cellphones, internet, mobile-operators

I found some posts about this matter but they don't have an updated review for 2015.

I wish to purchase a SIM card - something like prepaid card for just one month or two for vacations - for use in France & UK.

I'd like something like internet oriented. Do you know any company selling such services that you can recommend?

Comment: @JoErNanO He wants a SIM card that will work in France & The UK.

Comment: @JoErNanO That question only addresses France problem, I want to be able to use the SIM card in UK and not in "roaming mode"

Comment: @fedesismo you'll have to buy a local Sim card if you don't want to be in roaming mode.

Comment: @JoErNanO there is a big difference between using your local SIM in roaming mode and between using a roaming package. You are all very wrong about marking this question as a duplicate! you should know better than that.

Comment: @Joulupukki the French part of the question is definitely a duplicate. Somehow I'm sure we can find a duplicate for the UK part too.

Comment: @JoErNanO That's not a good logic. It's not about finding two mobile network operators that can give you prepaid internet service separately, it's about knowing one MNO that can give you a good deal -that works in both countries- without having to pay regular roaming fees

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Vodafone UK £30 Big Value Bundle will do if you don't use that much of data.

[image]

[Source](http://www.vodafone.co.uk/shop/bundles-and-sims/pay-as-you-go-plans/)